# How to build a list of unique values and display an array of their ids?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

This code is a simplified version of the concept I'm trying to achieve. In reality I'm working with the results of a somewhat complex query - but I figured this simple example would be enough.

I'm trying to output an ordered list of unique values with an array of their id's.  I'm unsure if I need to use one or two select statement, or if I should use one select statement and some ruby code.

**The data** (people)

```
id: first: last:
1   Julie  Brown
2   Julie  Brown
3   Mike   Smith
4   Julie  Brown
5   Andrea Smith
6   Mike   Smith
7   Jim    Brown
```

**Desired output**

```
Jim Brown (7)
Julie Brown (1, 2, 4)
Andrea Smith (5)
Mike Smith (3, 6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@people = Person
  .select(:first, :last, "array_agg(id) AS ids")
  .group(:first, :last)
```

You could use the `array_agg` function to get all the ids in a single query.

```
@people.each do |person|
  full_name = [person.first, person.last].join(" ")
  puts "#{ full_name } (#{ person.ids.join(", ") })"
end
```